# Create Email List From SQL Developer Data

Tags: sql

I want to export a list of email addresses ready to be copy and pasted into a distibution list for an email.

The select statement is simple:

select user_email
from user_list
where other = 'Y'

What do I need to do to add an ';' to the end of each email?

Im looking to product: joe.bloggs@email.com;janebloggs@email.com; ect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_email,';' from user_list where other = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @List varchar(max)

SET @List = ''

SELECT @List = @List + ';' + user_email FROM user_list WHERE other = 'Y'

SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List, 2, 2000000000)

SELECT @List
```